# Bokeh (12.13) not working in Zeppelin

Tags: bokeh, apache-zeppelin

I'm trying to use Bokeh (v 12.13) in Zeppelin (0.7) on an AWS EMR cluster.

According to the documentation I've seen [here](https://www.zepl.com/viewer/notebooks/bm90ZTovL3pqZmZkdS90ZXN0L2VhMGI0ODQ0MzNhYjQxNjZhODg5MjI1ZjAxZWVjMjdiL25vdGUuanNvbg), I should be able to use the notebook output handler. Git shows there was an error with this in 12.10 but this was resolved in 12.11 (https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/7179)

[image: No Hook for Zeppelin]

Trying to work around this by outputting to file, I get garbled HTML returned to the calling paragraph, and the show() task never completes - I need to manually stop it.

[image: Output File -> No Dice]

Comment: user153765: would you delete the images you have added, and add the text in each as text? A formatting tool is available. Note that images are not compatible with clipboards, search engines and screen readers, and so are not usually a helpful format to provide this information. Thanks.

Comment: @halfer thank your advice.  I'll remind it and try to comment more specific reaosn.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the exception message:

> no display hook installed for notebook type 'Zeppelin'

The Bokeh project itself does not provide or maintain Zeppelin support. It only exposes a general extension mechanism that other people can use to support different notebooks, if they choose. For Zeppelin to work, you'll need to install the third-party `bkzep` module:

https://github.com/zjffdu/bkzep